# Fundamental group of the union of two circles that intersect in two points

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

[image]

I need to find $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ where $X$ is the intersection of two circles (in $\mathbb{R^2}$). My idea is to use van Kampen, with $A,B,A\cap B$ as in figure. Both $A$ and $B$ are homotopic equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1$ (firstly I deformation retract $A$ to $S^1$ united a diameter, then I can contract the diameter to a point). $A\cap B$ is homotopic equivalent to $S^1$. Then $\pi_1(X,x_0)=\pi_1(A,x_0)*_{\pi_1(A\cap B,x_0)}\pi_1(B,x_0)=(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z})*_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z})$.I think the result should be $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ but I don't know how to prove it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you know CW-complexes?

Comment: No we have not studied them yet

Comment: Do you mean union of two circles? The intersection of two distinct circles is either empty, a point, or two points.

Comment: Yes, the union of two circles intersecting in two points

Answer (score 2):

Collaps one of the (short) segments connecting the two intersection points to a single point. This map is a homotopy equivalence. The resulting space is $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$ whose fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I don't understand why the map is a homotopy equivalence: it looks like A is generated by the loops that turn around the small circle and the big one...

Comment: @VANESSAVICHI It is a simlilar argument as that you use in your question. "... $S^1$ united a diameter, then I can contract the diameter to a point." If you can properly prove that the map contracting the diameter in $S^1$ united a diameter to a point is a homotopy equivalence, then you can do the same here. This is technically complicated, but it works. If you would know CW-complexes, then you could invoke the following theorem: If $X$ is a CW-complex and $A$ a contractible subcomplex, then the quotient map $p : X \to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is clear, I’ll try to write it down properly